# Keep randomly getting warning: "Sending `purchase-updated` with no listeners registered." when using the react-native-iap package

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

In the docs (https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/guides/purchases) there is an example of adding these listeners in a class based react component and I tried to convert it to functional component style.

The issue is that when the purchase goes trough on iOS and the purchase is supposed to come as a parameter to that `purchaseUpdatedListener` but only thing that happens is a warning: **"Sending purchase-updated with no listeners registered."**

And this happens very inconsistently since some purchases come without an issue but others just throw that warning and nothing happens in the `purchaseUpdatedListener`. This code is located at the `App.tsx` so it cannot be initialized earlier anywhere in the code.

```js
   useEffect(() => {
        const addListeners = async () => {
            await initConnection();

            try {
                   if (Platform.OS === SubscriptionPlatform.android) {
                      return flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid();
                    }
            } catch (error) {
                // Exception can happen here if there are pending purchases that are still pending
                // You can handle the error as per your requirements
            }

            const purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(async purchase => {
                console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
                if (
                    purchase?.productId &&
                    purchase?.transactionId &&
                    purchase?.transactionReceipt
                ) {
                    await finishTransaction({ purchase });
                }
            });

            const purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener(error => {
                console.warn('purchaseErrorListener', error);
            });

            return () => {
                if (purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
                    purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
                }

                if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
                    purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
                }
                endConnection();
            };
        };

        addListeners();
    }, []);
```

I've tried to move the code bit to different locations in the codebase but the most successes has came from the code being in `App.tsx`. I can't really think of anything more that would cause this issue.

Just wondering if anyone else has run in to the same issue.